# Xamarin редактор: что-то пошло не так

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xamarin, mobile-development

Прикрепляю скриншот, так как текст ошибки не копируется

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробности ошибки:

```
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(Unknown Source)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(Unknown Source)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.parseStartTag(Unknown Source)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(Unknown Source)
org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(Unknown Source)
mono.android.LayoutParser.next(LayoutParser.java:75)
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeXmlBlockParser.next(BridgeXmlBlockParser.java:305)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:841)
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:866)
android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323)
com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394)
com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:271)
mono.android.DesignerSession.loadInternal(DesignerSession.java:273)
mono.android.DesignerSession.lambda$load$0(DesignerSession.java:223)
mono.android.MonoDroidBroker.executeInMonoDroidContext(MonoDroidBroker.java:76)
mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:223)
mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:676)
mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

В общем, когда я заходил в проект в прошлый раз (2 дня назад) он работал, но сегодня выдаёт вот такую странную ошибку. В чём суть ошибки?

Comment: Глючит дизайнер, это бывает. Закройте его, скомпилируйте проект и снова попробуйте открыть его.

Comment: Почистите bin и obj папки и пересоберите проект.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Сделал, как вы оба говорили, не помогло. Порылся по форумам, вычитал, что после обновления вижуалки до текущей новейшей версии, у всех начала происходить такая фигня, надеюсь скоро пофиксят(

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте убрать строку в TextView и сбилдить проект,а потом открыть дизайнер[image: вот эту]